# While accessing second base class method from derived class getting this error in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

1. This is My code

In This block of code I'm trying to achieve example of inheritance in c++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Humnas
{
public:
    void brith()
    {
        cout << "Human has taken brith" << endl;
    }
};

class Male : public virtual Humnas
{
public:
    void gender()
    {
        cout << "Gender is male" << endl;
    }
};

class feMale : public virtual Humnas
{
public:
    void Gender()
    {
        cout << "Gender is female" << endl;
    }
};

class student : public Male, feMale
{
public:
    void schl(char sname[10])
    {
        cout << "Taken admission in " << sname << endl;
    }
};

class pro : public Male, feMale
{
public:
    void prof(char pname[10])
    {
        cout << "Working as a :- " << pname << endl;
    }
};

class child : public virtual Male, feMale
{
public:
};

int main()
{
    child c1, c2;
    char sname[10] = "Pradip";
    char pname[10] = "teacher";
    // c1.schl(sname);
    c2.brith();
    c1.brith();
    c1.gender();
    c1.Gender();
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rdYEWro1j

2. This is Output.

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:64:15: error: 'void feMale::Gender()' is inaccessible within this context
   64 |     c1.Gender();
      |               ^
<source>:26:10: note: declared here
   26 |     void Gender()
      |          ^~~~~~
<source>:64:15: error: 'feMale' is not an accessible base of 'child'
   64 |     c1.Gender();
      |               ^
<source>:58:10: error: unused variable 'sname' [-Werror=unused-variable]
   58 |     char sname[10] = "Pradip";
      |          ^~~~~
<source>:59:10: error: unused variable 'pname' [-Werror=unused-variable]
   59 |     char pname[10] = "teacher";
      |          ^~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple inheritance with comma doesn't preserve previous visibility, you need to repeat `public`:

```
class pro : public Male, public feMale
//                       ^^^^^^
```